# WCF - "There was no endpoint listening at..." error

Tags: wcf

I have two applications that I want to test locally on the same machine. App 1 has a simple WCF service with the folloiwng config entry:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="MyNamespace.ContainerManagementServiceBehavior"
        name="MyNamespace.ContainerManagementService">
  <endpoint address="ContainerManagementService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
     name="ContainerManagementbasicHttpEndpoint"
     contract="MyNamespace.IContainer" />
  <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  <host>
    <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ContainerManagementService" />
    </baseAddresses>
  </host>
</service>    
<behaviors>      
  <behavior name="MyNamespace.ContainerManagementServiceBehavior">
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
  </behavior>
</behaviors>
```

I start the service by running the web application project where it is hosted. I am able to successfully browse to the url and get web service information page from ie. I copy the same URL and use it for my client.

My other client, App 2, has the following in its config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="basicHttp" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
        openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
        sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
        hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="5242880" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880" messageEncoding="Text"
        textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192"
          maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="5242880" />
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None"
            proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint
      address="http://localhost:3227/Services/ContainerManagementService.svc"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp"
      contract="MyService.IService" name="externalService" />      
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

However, when I try to execute a WCF call form client to the running service, I get the following error message:

```
There was no endpoint listening at
http://localhost:3227/Services/ContainerManagementService.svc
that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect
address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

What could be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks likes the issue is due to the fact that both server and client are being run from the Cassini server. I am changing the architecture to host the server endpoint in IIS.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have two applications ?

One which hosts the server endpoint and the other which is the client ? Are both active in IIS (considering the second application is a web app) ?

If you have two projects for those two components in your solution, you can configure VS to start both project at the same time. This way you can put breakpoints on both the client and the server and see if the server really gets called by the client or if the exception happens without the server method being called.

Comment: I have two separate solutions one for Server one for Client. The solutions are run concurrently. The server is active in IIS.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the method of the svc.cs, does the breakpoint get hit or is it never called ? edit: and since both the client and server are on your machine you can get them to start from the same VS debugging session if both client and server are in the same solution. If they aren't you can make a solution with both for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

If your web service is on: http://localhost:8000/ContainerManagementService.svc

Your client app2 should point on this same addres:

```
<client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/ContainerManagementService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp"
        contract="MyService.IService" name="externalService" />      
</client>
```

Comment: He's most likely hosting in IIS, and thus, IIS will dictate the URL, based on where the *.svc file lives

Comment: It is not on http://localhost:8000/ContainerManagementService.svc which brings me to another question: it seems that <baseAddres> element is ignored in my scenario. Why? And where is it used?