# No endpoint listening wcf/rest

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, rest

So my previous question revolved around turning wcf into a restful service [convert a WCF Service, to a RESTful application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854052/wcf-service-application-to-restful), which I managed to do with some help!

But I am running into a new problem from my client:

> There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:26535/Service1.svc that could accept the message.
>   This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See
>   InnerException, if present, for more details.

Now the restful service runs as can be seen from a screen dump:

[image]

And I can add from the url the value 1 like so:

[image]

But yet I cant seem to run it on another new instance of visual studio, my client app.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="WebHttpBinding_IService1">
                    <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
                        messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
                        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    </textMessageEncoding>
                  <httpTransport></httpTransport>
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:26535/Service1.svc" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding_IService1"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="WebHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Client code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public ServiceReference1.Service1Client testClient = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = testClient.GetData(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
        }
    }
}
```

I was looking at previous problems in this area on SO here: [WCF - "There was no endpoint listening at..." error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463547/wcf-there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at-error)

But it provides no solution? Im not familiar with hosting on IIS or what not this is just practice so having it work on debug (F5) would be zer goood!

Comment: What is your inner exception? That might shed more light on this.

Comment: Doing an inner exception just says the remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might actually be due to the change to the REST service.

Try removing/commenting out this from your host config

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

It seems that REST does not pass over any metadata (thus the removal of the mex)

If you then reset your service reference, it should work properly...I believe.

Also, [this article](http://forums.asp.net/t/1695037.aspx/1) might prove useful

If you are able to use a third party, then I would suggest using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/). It makes consuming RESTful services extremely easy :)

Or you could use the newer WebAPI that can make these calls more direct also? The problem is that RESTful services are not as easily consumed the way SOAP calls are/were

Comment: if I change the binding in my client to webhttpbinding I get an error updating the servicereference which says: config for service reference could not be updated due to the following issue: the dinding at `system.servicemodel/binding/webhttpbinding` does not have a configured binding named `webhttpbindig_Iservice1` this is and invalid value binding at `app.config line 17`

Comment: OK, put the customBinding back in, but keep the mex out of the service and see what happens :)...this article also makes me believe that this might still be sending a POST, when you are looking for a GET now... http://forums.asp.net/t/1695037.aspx/1  can you use fiddler to see what is being sent across the wire?

Comment: Actually, above all this. I would suggest taking a look at RestSharp. I am not sure if you are able to use that or not, but it makes consuming REST services very simple

Comment: Nope nothing is being sent its failing at the client fiddler shows nothing across the wire so its defo a config problem, or that I cant host and serve a client in two different VS2010 Solutions? Microsoft is utter garbage arghh

Comment: This is not very restful, but can you try changing your WebGet to a WebPost just to see if that might be the problem (put the MEX back in and everything else as it was before these recent changes )

Comment: whats the namespace for webpost? webget uses serviceModel.Web but web post doesnt?

Comment: same again as before the meta data error on debug variable named 'value' which does not have type 'string'.

Comment: There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:26535/Service1.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Comment: Sorry, Im tapped on my WCF Restful client stuff...I am guessing you cannot use RestSharp? What about the new Microsoft WebAPI?